# devtools::install dependencies with multiple threads

Tags: r, multithreading, installation, package, devtools

I do have my own package, which I want to install via `devtools` including all its dependencies and their dependencies to. Since this turns out to be quite a list of packages, I'm looking for an way to install them in a multi-core mode like `utils::install.packages(Ncpus = 48, c("pak_1", "pak_n"))` lets you do.

So I tried `devtools::install(pkg = getwd(), Ncpus = 2)` which should work, since [the docu](https://devtools.r-lib.org/reference/install.html) shows `...` which leads you to [`install_deps`](https://remotes.r-lib.org/reference/install_deps.html), which in turns leads you to [`utils::install.packages`](https://rdrr.io/r/utils/install.packages.html).

But in practice I get a:

```
We detected these problematic arguments:
* `Ncpus`

Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Warning.

Do you have an idea how one can install packages via `devtools` in a multi-core fashion?

Comment: Have you tried `devtools::install_local(packagename, dependencies = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`devtools::install*` functions take `threads = N` not `Ncpu`.  `threads` will default to `Ncpu` if you have defined it in .`Rprofile`.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.6/topics/install